# Vim: remap on every mode except visual

Tags: vim

I am doing a key mapping when in visual mode:

```
:vnoremap Ó b
```

However, for all other modes, I need to have another mapping. Is there a way to do something like:

```
:'vremap
```

to specify all other modes? Currently I'm doing something very long-winded, like:

```
"Simulate option-shift arrow keys to highlight chunks of text
:vnoremap Ó bv
:vnoremap Ò el
:vnoremap Ô j
:vnoremap  k

:nnoremap Ó <Esc>vb
:nnoremap Ò <Esc>vel
:nnoremap Ô <Esc>vj
:nnoremap  <Esc>vk

:inoremap Ó <Esc>lvb
:inoremap Ò <Esc>lve
:inoremap Ô <Esc>vj
:inoremap  <Esc>vk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do something like `:'vremap` to specify all other modes?

As @Chelz pointed out, there is no map command for "all modes". There are, however, several ways to avoid having to define the same mapping multiple times for multiple modes.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43595915/3319589), the author illustrates how to use a for loop to map to more than one mode at the same time:

```
for map_command in ['nnoremap', 'inoremap']
  execute map_command . ' <silent> Ó <Esc>vb'
  execute map_command . ' <silent> Ò <Esc>vel'
  execute map_command . ' <silent> Ô <Esc>vj'
  execute map_command . ' <silent>  <Esc>vk'
endfor
```

And in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13854888/3319589), a wrapper function is used to achieve the same:

```
function! MapBoth(keys, rhs)
    execute 'nnoremap' a:keys a:rhs
    execute 'inoremap' a:keys a:rhs
endfunction

call MapBoth('Ó', '<Esc>lvb')
call MapBoth('Ò', '<Esc>lve')
call MapBoth('Ô', '<Esc>vj')
call MapBoth('', '<Esc>vk')
```

With these solutions, you will only have to define the mappings once.

Disclaimer: I have not tried the solutions above, but please let us know if they do not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the documentation `:h map`, there you will find the following:

```
:no[remap]  {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-nvo|   *:no*  *:noremap* *:nor*
:nn[oremap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-n| *:nn*  *:nnoremap*
:vn[oremap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-v| *:vn*  *:vnoremap*
:xn[oremap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-x| *:xn*  *:xnoremap*
:snor[emap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-s| *:snor* *:snore* *:snoremap*
:ono[remap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-o| *:ono* *:onoremap*
:no[remap]! {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-ic|    *:no!* *:noremap!*
:ino[remap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-i| *:ino* *:inor* *:inoremap*
:ln[oremap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-l| *:ln*  *:lnoremap*
:cno[remap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-c| *:cno* *:cnor* *:cnoremap*
:tno[remap] {lhs} {rhs}     |mapmode-t| *:tno* *:tnoremap*
```

there does not seem to be an option for what you are looking for.

Comment: What is `xn` and all the items down from hat?

Comment: @David542 each mode has an own help page, just take a look. I have never used some of those before

Comment: xnoremap is visual mode only. Vnoremap actually includes select mode